# What date/time functions to use for PHP 5.2

Tags: php

The DateTime, DateInterval etc. classes are not available at the server I am using (PHP 5.2)

Which functions should I use instead?

Comment: What for ? I suppose you could use strtotime + date.

Comment: The calculations needed are a little more complex than that. I would need more capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the PHP Manual pages for [DateTime](http://il.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateInterval](http://il.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php), you can see which version is required for a specific function right below the method name, e.g.

> DateInterval::createFromDateString
>   (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)

indicates this method is available from PHP5.3 on.

Like already pointed out in other answers, some of the DateTime (but not DateInterval) methods are already regularly available as of 5.2. As an alternative, you can use the regular [Date functions](http://il.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php). Note that many of the functions prefixed with `date_` and `timezone_` are aliases for their respective OOP counterparts in `DateTime` and `DateTimezone`, so you will not be able to use them, if you cannot use them now.

If you want an OO lib for dates, have a look at [`Zend_Date`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.date.html) or [`PEAR_Date`](http://pear.php.net/package/Date).

Comment: Actually, DateTime::modify($string) works nicely with servers running PHP<5.3 Solved my problem.

Comment: Am I the only one to find that being presented with a list of 50 functions/methods in the PHP doc and having to click each one in order to know whether it’s available in PHP 5.2 is utterly ridiculous?

Answer (score 3):

DateTime is part of PHP 5.2 core; however 5.3 added some more methods that weren't available in 5.2

DateInterval, on the other hand, appears to be unique to PHP 5.3.

Are you sure DateTime isn't available at all?  Are you sure you're using PHP 5.2?

Try calling `class_exists('DateTime')` and `phpversion()`

Answer (score 0):

> Note: Experimental DateTime support in PHP 5.1.x
>   Although the DateTime class (and related functions) are enabled by default since PHP 5.2.0, > it is possible to add experimental support into PHP 5.1.x by using the following flag
>   before configure/compile: CFLAGS=-DEXPERIMENTAL_DATE_SUPPORT=1

As can be read on php.net
So DateTime should be available on 5.2.0

Answer (score -1):

[Here's a reference](http://il.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php) of the date/time functions you can use.

Comment: That list is not specific to 5.2.