# Add a duration to a date by DateInterval

Tags: php, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What date/time functions to use for PHP 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369082/what-date-time-functions-to-use-for-php-5-2)

I want to add a duration to a date, I set this code :

```
$date = new DateTime(Date('r'));
$date = $date->format("d-m-Y H:i:s");                       
$interval = new DateInterval('PT1H2M3S');        
$date = $date->add($interval);        
echo $date;
```

and I get this error : Class 'DateInterval' not found

Why is this and how can I modify the date without DateInterval?

Comment: `DateInterval` is PHP >= 5.3 only. You probably have an older version of PHP running.

Comment: See as well [DateInterval & DatePeriod alternative for PHP 5.2x](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?726121-DateInterval-amp-DatePeriod-alternative-for-PHP-5.2x) and [Date interval add and sub prior to PHP 5.3](http://www.pixelstech.net/article/index.php?id=1319208610)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use `strtotime`. Maybe not the best, but certainly the easiest way:

```
echo date("d-m-Y H:i:s",strtotime("2012-02-15 1 hour 2 min 3 sec"));
```

or if you need the interval from now use just:

```
echo date("d-m-Y H:i:s",strtotime("1 hour 2 min 3 sec"));
```

Comment: +1 because its the only answer so far that actually tries to give the OP a solution instead of merely stating the obvious

Comment: you can also try with DateTime::modify which is available as PHP 5.2.0

Answer (score 12):

### Cause

[`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) was added in PHP 5.3 as mentioned on the manual page:

> The DateInterval class
>
> (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)

### PHP Version Upgrade

You can find out what version of PHP you are using by running [`phpversion()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php):

```
echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();
```

If you are running a version less than 5.3 you will need to upgrade it to use `DateInterval`.

### Alternative

As at @Gordon mentions you can use [`DateTime::modify()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php), for example:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2006-12-12');
$date->modify('+1 day');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

To add one day to your date object.

Comment: I feel the question could be improved by explaining how to achieve the desired outcome without using `DateInterval`, for instance with `DateTime::modify`. Right now it's just stating the obvious explanation of why the OP get's the error.

Comment: @Gordan I see you have updated the question. I answered the original question accurately and I gave a valid solution - upgrade PHP in my answer above. From a security point of view support for PHP 5.2 is dead now so an upgrade is a good idea anyway.

Comment: You can easily see by the accepted answer that the OP was not just looking for the obvious explanation but for an alternative that works for his setup. My edit to the question only made it more clear. Regarding PHP 5.2.x being dead: yes, but there is still an awful lot of shared hosts out there running it. Also note that I didnt say your question was invalid or inaccurate (since you stress that). I only said that it could be improved by giving the OP the alternative he is looking for (and its not like adding a link to DateTime::modify would have broke your fingers). But ok, +0 then from me.

Comment: Fair enough :) I didn't see the point in updating my answer as this question is getting closed hard anyway, but I have anyway.